# how to stop a drag event in jquery ui

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a jquery ui as follows:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  drag: function(event, ui){
    if(this.offsetTop > 0 || this.offsetLeft > 0) return false;
  }
})
```

Basically I want it so that every time user drags, i want to continuously test for a condition to be true (in this case, i want the top and left side of draggable to stick to the side of parent).

I thought the above code will just cancel that particular drag event, but it seems to have stopped dragging altogether. Any idea how to just cancel a drag event when a condition is satisfied?

Thanks a lot!

Jason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To keep the draggable alive, don't return false. From what you say, you probably need to do something to limit the position of the dragged (ui) element.

Here's a fiddle I put together in response to another SE question.

http://jsfiddle.net/XLrNF/